# Layout appears offset on the top

Tags: java, android, kotlin, androidx

I want to fix how the layout appears offset on the top. Below is my code two screenshots of the problem.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_default">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rutasList"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

This is the designer:

[image: designer]

This is the image on an emulator, happens also in real device:

[image: emulator]

Comment: It's helpful if you can specify the correct expectation too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want, I guess that in the designer mode the RecyclerView items are on the top left... Well, that's how it's supposed to be. In the designer mode, when you use any sort of listed property (ListView, GirdView, RecycelerView, etc.) they appear as their "native" look. so what you see here is perfectly fine.